# Javascript: Problem adding array into 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to shuffle an array and add the shuffled-set every time into 2D array using a loop.
the problem is that the resulted 2D array contains the same shuffled-set for all rows, while the output of each shuffled-set is different.

So; what do I miss here?

```
var b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var matrix=[];

for(var i=0; i <5; i ++){
    shuffle(b);
    matrix[i]=b;
    //matrix.push(b);
    console.log(b);
}
console.log(matrix);


function shuffle(array) {
    var ctr = array.length, temp, index;
    while (ctr > 0) {
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctr);
        ctr--;
        temp = array[ctr];
        array[ctr] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

the output:

```
Array(9) [ 7, 3, 4, 9, 2, 1, 6, 8, 5 ]
Array(9) [ 5, 6, 3, 9, 8, 4, 1, 7, 2 ]
Array(9) [ 9, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6, 8, 7, 1 ]
Array(9) [ 3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 9, 6, 8, 7 ]
Array(9) [ 5, 9, 4, 6, 7, 3, 2, 8, 1 ]

(5) […]
0: Array(9) [ 5, 9, 4, … ]
1: Array(9) [ 5, 9, 4, … ]
2: Array(9) [ 5, 9, 4, … ]
3: Array(9) [ 5, 9, 4, … ]
4: Array(9) [ 5, 9, 4, … ]
length: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one 1D array object, i.e. `b`. And you keep shuffling and adding that *same* object reference to `matrix`:

```
 matrix[i]=b;
```

So even after you have added such a row, you will keep mutating that added row when you call `shuffle` again.

You should take a copy of the array so you have *different* arrays that get added to `matrix`:

```
 matrix[i]=b.slice();
```

There are several ways to get a copy: `b.slice()` can also be `Array.from(b)`, or `[...b]`.

Alternatively, you could put the initalisation of `b` as new array, *inside* the loop:

```
var matrix = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    var b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    shuffle(b);
    matrix[i] = b;
}
```

As you have designed `shuffle` to return the array also, you can reduce the above code to:

```
var matrix = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    matrix[i] = shuffle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could take a shallow clone of your shuffle.

```
 for(var i=0; i <5; i ++){
    const clone = {...shuffle(b)};
    matrix[i]=clone;
    //matrix.push(b);
    console.log(clone);
}
console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: Note that `{...shuffle(b)}` is not an array instance.